# fire a trigger on existing data?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Setup:

A--< B >-- C . On A there is a RFS on B, and then there is an after update trigger that when run populates fields on B. One of B's Fields are then rolled-up into a field on C.

Question:

The trigger works, but i need to run it on the existing records in the DB to bring everything up to date. How do I do that? I already tried running a 'force mass recalculation with the RFS  on A and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out a work-around.

Use Data loader- do an export on Id's and the update. this will change the last modified date, and cause the after update trigger to fire.

Answer (score 8):

You could write rather simple [Batch Apex (see docs)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) job class to touch all records you want to recalculate:

```
global class TouchRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    private String query;

    global TouchRecords(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        update scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

The job can then be executed by running the following (for example via execute anonymous):

```
Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(new TouchRecords('select id from A__c'));
```

or

```
Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(new TouchRecords('select id from Contact'));
```

to touch all contacts

This should run the trigger on all records being touched (supports max 50 million records). Same idea as the proposed dataloader solution, but kept inside SFDC for easier reuse

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to create a dummy field on the object and then do a bulk update on that field. There could be further issues with this, so you would want to reduce the batch size to a number so that you do not SOQL governor limit if doing any DML.